# WAP browser keypad navigation

Tags: html, mobile, wap

In some mobile browsers, pressing a number on the keypad, launches a link that is on the page in a WAP "navigation bar".

```
0 | Home
1 | Contact Us
2 | Products
```

When I would tap 2, it would click the products link for me. How do I setup my html to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [access keys](http://www.developershome.com/wap/wcss/wcss_tutorial.asp?page=accesskeyExtension) - you need to add an attribute to the link.
see also [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/accesskey.html)